# Arch Linux booting with read only filesystems

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I installed Arch today and when I logged in I noticed that my filesystem is read only.

How can I fix this?

Comment: assuming fstab is misconfigured and /dev/sda1 is root.romount root as rw with  mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /;nano /etc/fstab-----and change fstab to mount it rw

Answer (score 0):

I would try to figure out why the boot process or kernel marked the file system as read-only.

Normally if something is detected during boot it will try to fix the filesystem with fsck and if it can't then not mount the filesystem.

I have seen running Linux servers switch their filesystems to read-only when there was a problem with the underlying SAN and the kernel couldn't write to the SAN.

As behrooz said, it might be something as simple - bug highly unlikely - as something changed your /etc/fstab file so that your filesystems are read-only.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check your /etc/fstab.... do you see the flags as (rw). if not, you might want to boot from the install CD/USB Pen Drive and modify the fstab file to (rw).